# Как повесить события кнопок, чтобы при нажатии они имитровали e.keyCode цифр и клавише bakspace?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как повесить события кнопок, чтобы при нажатии они имитровали e.keyCode цифр и клавише bakspace?
В моем случае позиция курсора при нажатии по кнопкам работет не корректно как если бы я вводил значения с клавиатуры. При вводе значениий с помощью кнопок виртуальной клавиатуры курсор должен быть в конце введенного символа(цифры)

```js
$(function() {

  $('input[name="mobile"]').inputmask("+7(999) 999-99-99");

  $('.numeric-input').keyboard({
    layout: 'custom',
    autoAccept: 'true',
    customLayout: {
      'default': [
        '7 8 9',
        '4 5 6',
        '1 2 3',
        '0 {bksp}',
        'accept'
      ]
    },
    usePreview: false,
    position: { of: null, // null (attach to input/textarea) or a jQuery object (attach elsewhere)
      my: 'left top', // keyboard itself
      at: 'left top', // input or textarea that the keyboard is attached to
      at2: 'left bottom' // used when "usePreview" is false (centers the keyboard at the bottom of the input/textarea)
    }
  })



});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.27.3/css/keyboard.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.27.3/js/jquery.keyboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.27.3/js/jquery.keyboard.extension-caret.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.27.3/js/jquery.keyboard.extension-typing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.27.3/js/jquery.keyboard.extension-previewkeyset.min.js"></script>


<input name="mobile" type="text" placeholder="+7(___)___-__-__" class="inptext phone_activation numeric-input" value="+7">
```